# Getting the character code for a number

Tags: java, casting, char, int

How can I can get the char representation of an integer in the range 0 - 9 ?
Given that digit1 is an integer in that range,
I've tried

```
char1 = (char) digit1;
System.out.printf("%s", Character.toString(char1));
```

and also

```
char1 = 'digit1';  
System.out.printf("%s", Character.toString(char1));
```

But each time it prints a "weird" character whereas I was expecting the corresponding one-digit integer.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong in the printing or  somewhere else?
THanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the value `0` with the ASCII character `'0'`.

Any of the following would work:

```
System.out.printf("%d", digit);
System.out.printf("%c", digit + '0');
System.out.printf("%s", Character.toString((char)(digit + '0')));
```

Comment: +1 for the solution that doesn't require memorizing the ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 char1 = digit1 + '0';
```

`char1` then contains a character representing the `digit1`.